# Building structure Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to place a string into the structure index 0 inside a structure array but i keep on segmentation fault. Anyone know whats going on?? I tokenize the string by comma,sending the name and age token to a function that builds the array, the function should enter the name and number into the structure but every time i try to add a entry into the structure array from outside where it was declared i get segmentation faults so am i trying to enter these elements incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct info{
    char name[20];
    int age;

};

void buildarray(struct info array[],char* namee,char* age);

int main()
{
    struct info arrays[3];
    char buffer[] = "john,25";
    char* del = ",";
    char* token;
    char* number;
    char* name;

    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    name = token;
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL,del);
        number = token;
    }
    buildarray(arrays,name,number);

    printf("%s %d",arrays[0].name,arrays[0].age);


}

void buildarray(struct info array[],char* namee,char* age)
{
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(array[0].name,namee);
    int amount = atoi(age);
    array[0].age = amount;
}
```

Comment: What line is the segfault occurring on?

Comment: If you print name and number before calling build_array, what are the values?

Comment: You are segfaulting because ```age``` is ```null```.

Comment: regarding this line: while(token != NULL)  That line keeps trying to extract tokens until the token pointer is NULL.  Just remove the while loop construct and simply say:   token = strtok(NULL,del);
        number = token;  Since your variable are actually pointers, your code would be much more readable if such pointer were distinguished, perhaps with a leading 'p'

Answer (score 4):

```
while(token != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL,del);
    number = token;
}
buildarray(arrays,name,number);
```

On the last pass, when `token` is `NULL`, `number` is `NULL` too. You then call `buildarray` passing it a `NULL`, which it passes to `atoi`. Boom.